# Pass data from widget to app, without dev-account

Tags: xcode6

I succedeed to get my app running on my actual device without developer account!
My problem now is that I want to share NSUserDefaults data from my app to a widget.. And guess what, to let these two communicate I need a dev account...  Is there any way to get this working without dev account? Or is there maybe a public account for people who just want to test their widget?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't because in widget communicate with app to container target we are using `NSUserDefaults` and for passing this data we need to create a App Group using valid application provisional profile and code sign.

So if you have not developer account and you are trying to communicate two target without app group you can not pass the data using `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: Is there any orher way to pass data without dev account? The data is just an integer, shown in a label

Comment: i dont think so. and i am not sure if you can do with some trick might be apple not accept it.